# Keycloak: Not able to load admin GUI/console

Tags: java, user-interface, keycloak, rocky-os

We have installed [Keycloak](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/20.0.3/keycloak-20.0.3.zip) Latest version[**20.0.3**] into the VM.
With the help of kc shell script trying to start the Keycloak

```
./kc.sh start --http-enabled true --hostname <IP-ADDRESS>
```

Up to here everything is fine and I was able to view the home screen of Keycloak but when it redirecting[http://:8080/admin/master/console/] to login into the admin console its struck and not loading

[image]

My browser Developer tool showing this error

> Timeout when waiting for 3rd party check iframe message.

1. Linux Rocky 6.5
2. Java 11

**Note:-**

When i am using development mode everything works fine.

```
 ./kc.sh start-dev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Keycloak is running in Production mode over HTTPS, the aforementioned issue may arise if you are using **IPADDRESS** in place of **HOSTNAME** to access Keycloak UI.
So one solution is use below command

```
./kc.sh start --http-enabled true --hostname <HOSTNAME>
```

and then access Keycloak UI with this url

```
https://<HOSTNAME>:PORT
```

Another dirty Solution is ,set Below parameters

```
 export KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT= "false"
 export KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS= "false"
 export KC_HTTP_ENABLED= "true"
```

And Start Keycloak like this and access through IPADDRESS

```
./kc.sh start --http-enabled=false --https-key-store-password=secret --proxy edge
```

Answer (score 7):

To fix this error add the environment variables:

> KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"   KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: "false"
> KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"   KC_PROXY: edge